# Is there a better way to not repeat myself (ruby)?

Tags: ruby

Is there a better way of writing this?  I don't like having to write the word 'response' three times in one row

```
puts 'Good Day! Would you like a practice program?'

choices = [1,2,3,4,5]

while true
  response = gets.chomp
  if  response == 'yes' || response =='YES' || response == 'Yes' 
    puts 'Here\'s your number.'
    puts choices.sample
    break
  else
    puts 'try again.'
  end 
end
```

Comment: I wish codereview.stackexchange.com was a functional-enough site to have these things questions live there instead

Comment: Thanks for the help all! This has been a fascinating experience in ways Ruby can skin a cat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
  response = gets.chomp
  if  response.downcase == 'yes'
   # statements
  else
   # statements
  end
```

Here response value 'yes' can be of any combination of letters in value like

> yes, Yes, yEs, yeS, YES, YeS, yES, etc.

Comment: Almost good, but not good to write meaningless empty regexes.

Comment: Also, no need to separate `chomp` and `downcase` in different steps.

Comment: Also, this does not do exactly what OP is asking for (although that may not become an issue). It matches input like `yEs`. You should at least mention that fact. If you haven't noticed the difference, then this answer is wrong.

Comment: @sawa Then, we can write like if((response = gets.chomp.downcase).eql?('yes') )

Comment: @AlokAnand No.. Sawa's point is correct. He tried to say you, don't assume by yourself. OP didn't mention that OP can different combination of `"yesy"`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Got the point, that's why mentioned possible values of response variable in the answer.

Comment: @AlokAnand OP didn't mentione that any combination of `yes`. If he did, I would write `response[/yes/i]`. But as OP didn't, I didn't :)

Comment: +1. Although not exactly the answer to the question OP posed, it is clearly the right solution.

Comment: @KaptajnKold thank you, but answer givenn by slapthelownote is the perfect answer considering required possibilities and code performance

Answer (score 4):

another way, just for the sake of it:

```
['Yes', 'YES', 'yes'].include? response
```

Comment: Actually, this is the only answer so far that does exactly what OP is doing.

Answer (score 2):

I would write as below :

```
puts 'Good Day! Would you like a practice program?'

choices = [1,2,3,4,5]
# Kernel#loop repeatedly executes the block, until you break it 
loop do
  response = gets.chomp
  # Regexp#=== will be the good choice here to do the matching
  if  /^(yes|YES|Yes)$/ === response 
  # For any combination of yes values /^yes$/i === response
    puts %{Here's your number: #{choices.sample}}
    break
  else
    puts 'try again.'
  end 
end
```

Lets run the code :

```
C:\ruby>ruby so.rb
Good Day! Would you like a practice program?
no
try again.
yes
Here's your number: 3
```

Comment: Can you please add why you would write it like these?

Comment: Good approach, but you need anchors: `/Yes/ === 'No. Yesterday was Sunday.' => true.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regular Expression as a test in a case statement, the trailing `i` indicates case-insensitivity.

```
require 'readline'

choices = Array(1..5)

prompt = "Good Day! Would you like a practice program?"

loop do
  case Readline.readline(prompt + "\n")
  when /yes/i
    puts "Here's your number: #{choices.sample}"
    break
  else
    prompt = 'Try again:'
  end
end
```

Comment: Arup previously had the solution with `/yes/i`, but edited to another solution because this does not do exactly what OP is doing (although it is close, and may even be more practial). However, if you want to compare case-insensitively, then Alok's answer is more efficient.

Comment: @sawa After seeing your [cooment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147663/is-there-a-better-way-to-not-repeat-myself-ruby/22147719#comment33607527_22147697), I have noticed that. You have good eyes. :-) So I changed my answer, to fit it as per your comment.

Comment: @ArupRakshit It is not absolutely wrong. If you intentionally did it, and mentioned that it is an answer to a modified question, not the original one, then it should be okay.

Comment: @sawa I wouldn't put any effort, any on my answer. As viewers like `['Yes', 'YES', 'yes'].include? response`, but not `/yes|YES|Yes/ === response`.. I don't know, why my one is treated as not better one. If you look closely, its saves character typing also. Although I didn't check which one is faster. But thanks for your comment as always.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative from the above answers could be this.

```
['Yes'.downcase].include? response.downcase #=>
```

Edit: A better version after a valid comment

```
['yes'].include? response.downcase #=> true for "yEs"
```

Comment: Simple oversight.  Just remove first and your comment and I'll delete this comment.

Comment: Yes it is oversight. But don't remove your comment, I would prefer that it be there :-).